SAST Testing job not executing from gitlab
I am trying to perform SAST testing from my git pipeline. I have added the following to my gitlab-ci.yml file:
image: my-image-localtion

variables:  
   MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode"  
   MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true"

include:  
  - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

stages:  
  - test  
  - build  
  - deploy


(more stuff..)

Our gitlab server has the SAST plugin. I read that the above is all I need to add to the gitlab-ci.yml file for my project in order to execute SAST scanning. However, when you look at the execution of the pipeline, the job output says "pending" then:
This job is stuck because the project doesn't have any runners online assigned to it.

My understanding is that this job should automatically be assigned a default runner from gitlab, but clearly that's not happening. Another team using the SAST scanning from this same gitlab server does not need to explicitly add a runner to the job for the SAST testing, and their gitlab-ci.yml for this is identical to what I added.
Grateful for any suggestions. thank you

figured it out. On our gitlab server, we have shared runners that should pick up the SAST test job, but they have tags associated with them in order to be assigned a job. In my gitlab-ci.yml, I needed to explicitly define a job with a tag. I had not done that. here is what I added:
sast:
   stage: test
   tags:
     - java

The “java” tag is assigned to several of our runners, so it picked it up and ran to completion.
